# A question on the Klein-4 group and permutations.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I am pretty new to group theory, and need a little head-start on a proof.

Let $G = GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ be the group of two-by-two invertible matrices
over the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $V = \{e,a,b,c\}$ be the Klein $4$-group Let $α = \begin{pmatrix}
u & v\\
w & x
\end{pmatrix}$
be in $G$. Show that $\alpha$ defines a permutation
of the set $\{a,b, c\}$ by the rules: $\alpha (a) = a^u b^w, α(b) = a^v b^x$. Show that $G$ can be identified
with $S_3$, the symmetric group on 3 letters.

I suppose it wants me to show $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, but I'm not too sure how to do it.

Thanks again.

Comment: It tells you how: show the given rules define an action on a set of three elements. They gave you the formula, so verify it satisfies the requirements to be an action. This will induce a morphism to $S_3$, at which point you just have to check that it is one-to-one and surjective (the latter can be done by counting how many elements yoour group of matrices has).

Comment: The number of elements in the group is $(2^2-1)(2^2-2)=6$, and it is not Abelian. So it is $S_3$ (by Sylow theorem).

Comment: I changed $V =$ {$e,a,b,c$} to $V = \{e,a,b,c\}.$ The whole thing belongs inside just one pair of dollar signs, to get proper spacing and matching fonts and font sizes. $$V = \{e,a,b,c\}$$

Comment: The book has not introduced Cauchy's, Lagrange's, or the Sylow theorems. Is there any clean way to do it not using these? I suppose maybe it would be easier to show that there's only one non-abelian group of order 6, but how do you do this not using the above theorems?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun , it is "Introduction to Abstract Algebra" by Timothy J. Ford, a collection of his notes from his classes that he teaches.

Comment: Look at how the group *permutes* the elements $a,b,c$ of the Klein $4$-group under the given action. Use that to define the isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

So by counting the number of possible elements, $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is a group of order $6$, as is $S_3$. Thus to show that the map $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/2)\to S_3$ is an isomorphism it suffices to show that it is injective. But if we assume that we have some $\alpha \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/2)$ that is sent to the identity permutation, then we have by definition that $\alpha(x)=x$, for $x\in \{a,b,c\}$. Since we also have that $\alpha(e)=e$ by definition, we see that $\alpha$ is the identity on $V$. Thus we have injectivity and the map must be an isomorphism.